# HAProxy for MySQL Master-Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, haproxy, master-slave

We are having MySQL MASTER-SLAVE Replication setup and everything is working fine.

Currently all load (reads/writes) are going to MASTER server. Our application is having 99% reads and 1% writes.

We thought of distributing load (only reads) to both Master and Slave. So we thought of using HAProxy to distribute the load to both MySQL servers.

Our requirement is all writes to be redirected to only Master server and reads to be distributed between Master and Slave servers.

Comment: HA-proxy doesn't check if it is a read/write query.  (that is more application logic).  Your application should choose which server to query :  if 'write' then server A, else B..., then if you have server B run HA-proxy  it could balance all the queries it receives ('reads') between different DBservers

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented the same for my project.
I have two DB Server ( DB01, DB02 ) behind the Ha-Proxy (LB01). I hit ha-proxy assuming a DB from my application. in my application I distributed the database queries as read on 3307 and write on 3306 port.

in haproxy.cfg (configuration file HAPROXY) two LISTENER as :

```
listen mysql-cluster
    bind  *:3306
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option mysql-check user mast_ha
    server DB01 10.x.x.x:3306 check maxconn 100000 


listen mysql-cluster-replica
    bind  *:3307
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user mast_ha
    server DB02 10.x.x.x:3306 check maxconn 100000
```

And Distrubuted mysql call from application by making two jdbc template , one for read and another one for write.

Comment: how to to check its distributed the database queries as read on 3307 and write on 3306 port. plz explain :)

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully implemented our DB architecture for a very intensive read/write application.
We have one MASTER where all read/writes operations take place and 2 SLAVES (A, B) where all the reads take places. Usually, the master-slave replication assumes that reads go on slaves and all other things (reads and writes) on master. In other words, slaves balances the reads.

We put an HAProxy after the WebServer serving read request. The WebServer connects to slaves through the HAProxy. The HAProxy checks the status of the slaves and balances requests among master and slaves.
For easy the configuration, we put the DB servers on separated LANs.
The configuration of HAProxy is very simple: It is just enough to use the default configuration and change the listen statement. 
For example:

```
listen slaves 10.8.214.14:3306
    balance     roundrobin
    option tcpka
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy
    server  master   10.8.214.12:3306   check weight 1
    server  slave1   10.8.214.11:3306   check weight 1
    server  slave2   10.8.214.13:3306   check weight 1
```

Remember also to enable haproxy at boot.

If you want to go a step ahead, you could integrate the monitoring of slaves status (SQL errors or synchronization problems) by using some script. Ha proxy can use whatever agent you want.
Take a look [here](https://github.com/fujiwara/mysql-slave-healthcheck-agent) and [here](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/18/making-haproxy-1-5-replication-lag-aware-in-mysql/)

If you have a very intensive write applications I suggest to use the right storage engine, like TokuDB which scales very well with database size.

Comment: where you find out its read request or write request ? at code level

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Proxy has capability to split read/write split. and load balance multiple mysql servers behind it. The read/write split works for the most part expect for some complex statements.

> Disclaimer: MySQL Proxy is currently an Alpha release and should not be used within production environments.